# ASA Update OpenConnect Fatal SSL error

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, sslvpn

I've upgraded my ASA 5512-X from ASA 9.6(2) to ASA 9.8.1.

After the upgrade Openconnect fails with following Error

```
SSL connection failure: A TLS fatal alert has been received
```

I didn't change any configuration. It also worked before.

Anybody knows, what could lead to this error?

Comment: In order for us to give you proper help, please consider posting the full configuration of your ASA. Remember to remove any public IP adresses, usernames and passwords.

Comment: The software you have chosen is not safe harbor. It's recommended to always use safe harbor software. Did you upgrade the ASDM module as well?

Comment: The Support told me to use this Software. I had a problem with the upgrade assistent and he said I should manually install this version.
Yes. ASDM is v7.8.1. At the moment i don't have access to the config, but the config wasn't modifed.

Comment: Well if you don't have access to the configuration it's hard to help. The SSL certificate could be expired after upgrading. It might need a renewal.

Comment: It isn't. Checked that already. It is valid & trusted. This was also my first check. Also checked if it is possible to use TLS1.2. It is also. No I don't know.

Comment: In my personal opinion i would downgrade to 9.6.3, which is the recommended version from Cisco.

Comment: Couldn't this lead to a much more fatal problem on my ASA? Can I use ASDM 7.8.1 with ASA 9.6.3 or do i need to change this also ?

Comment: ASDM 7.8.1.150: Cisco Adaptive Security Device Manager for ASA 9.1, 9.2, 9.4, 9.6, 9.7, and 9.8. - so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in ASA 9.8.1. It is fixed in ASA 9.8.2 which is already available.